# Ruby build Hashes in Hashes in Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have special construction of Array and Hashes like this

```
[
  { Qid: '3', QName: 'Test1', filled_out: [
      { Id: '234', Date: '25.04.2015 23:14:15', Score: rand(10..100)},
      { Id: '4587',  Date: '27.04.2015 11:13:15', Score: rand(10..100)},
      { Id: '33254', Date: '23.05.2015 09:19:17', Score: rand(10..100)}
    ]
  },
  {
    Qid: '3', QName: 'Test2', filled_out: [
      { Id: '2478', Date: '25.04.2015 23:14:15', Score: rand(10..100) },
      { Id: '12357', Date: '27.04.2015 11:13:15', Score: rand(10..100) },
      { Id: '9654', Date: '23.05.2015 09:19:17', Score: rand(10..100) }
    ]
  },
  {
    Qid: '3', QName: 'Test3', filled_out: [
      { Id: '47854', Date: '25.04.2015 23:14:15', Score: rand(10..100) },
      { Id: '12365', Date: '27.04.2015 11:13:15', Score: rand(10..100) },
      { Id: '77788547', Date: '23.05.2015 09:19:17', Score: rand(10..100) }
    ]
  },
  {
    Qid: '3', QName: 'Test4', filled_out: [
      { Id: '1214', Date: '25.04.2015 23:14:15', Score: rand(10..100) },
      { Id: '5698', Date: '27.04.2015 11:13:15', Score: rand(10..100)},
      { Id: '1906', Date: '23.05.2015 09:19:17', Score: rand(10..100) }
    ]
  }
]
```

This construction is static by code. Now i want try to create this construction by randomizer.

I tried this code but it doesn't work

```
@arr = Array.new

rand(1..12).times do |i|
    @v = Hash.new
    @v[:Qid] = rand(10..1000)
    @v[:QName] = 'Test'
    @v[:filled_out] = nil

    rand(1..8).times do |k|
      @q = Hash.new
      @q[:Id] = rand(10..1000)
      @q[:Date] = '25.04.2015 23:14:15'
      @q[:Score] = rand(1..100)

      @v[:filled_out] << @q
    end
  @arr << @v
end
```

So whats wrong? Wht is the best way to realize that

Ruby says:

> "undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: I see two `do`s and one `end`.

Comment: I think there's a typo in `rand(1.8)` too

Comment: I don't see an `each` method.

Comment: The "end" exist after last line (@arr << @v). I only forgot to type here.

Comment: I fixed the rand(1.8) to rand(1..8). Now Ruby says: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `<<` with `=`

From `@v[:filled_out] << @q` to `@v[:filled_out] = @q`

`<<` is used for inserting item to array

Comment: Now Ruby says: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Comment: But it looks like the Hash will override each loop, not append, isn't it?

Comment: On which lines it gives the error? Look here I works without any error: http://is.gd/kwfJCN

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to build the arrays before hand and then iterate over them.

Here's an example I put together:

```
arr = Array.new(rand(1..12))

arr.each_with_index do |v, i|
  filled_out = Array.new(rand(1..8))

  filled_out.each_with_index do |j, k|
    filled_out[k] = {
      'Id': rand(10..1000),
      'Date': '25.04.2015 23:14:15',
      'Score': rand(1..100)
    }
  end

  arr[i] = {
    'Qid': rand(10..1000),
    'QName': "test",
    'filled_out': filled_out
  }

end

puts arr
```

You could probably drop the `each_with_index` with something else to save you from using uneeded variables but I just threw this together to show you a working example.

Sometimes when you are building data like this it's nice to use code that is more verbose in respect to the end result.